# Technical indicator MACD - Does the D stands for the Math divergence?

Tags: technical-analysis

Does the divergence from MACD is the same well known from [Math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence)?

What is the connection?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

divergence as in "moving away from", alternatively "difference between X and Y getting bigger".

Comment: Yes, just the simple everyday meaning of "divergence".